# 'Price does not have an id' error when trying to order a public virtual server using softlayer_product_order method

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I need to use the `softlayer_product_order` method to order a VM on a dedicated host.  To test ordering a public VM I am using the following container but no matter what different options I try I keep getting error 'price does not have an id'. I am ordering in the MEL01 DC using price IDs I have extracted by running `product_package.getItemPrices` on package IDs 46 and 835 (which seem to be the ones for VMs?)

```
order = {
            'complexType' : 'Softlayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest',
            'packageId' : 46,
            'quantity' : 1,
            'useHourlyPricing' : False,
            'virtualGuests' : [{ 'domain' : 'softlayer.com', 'hostname' : 'testServer1'}],
            'location' : 449596,
            "prices": [
{
  "id": 27023 # MONITORING_HOST_PING
},
{
  "id": 45462 # OS_CENTOS_7_X_MINIMAL_64_BIT
},
{
  "id": 32578 # GUEST_DISK_25_GB_SAN
},
{
  "id": 112867 # GUEST_CORES_2
},
{
  "id": 32500 # NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_AND_TICKET
},
{
  "id": 112353 # RAM_4_GB
},
{
  "id": 23070 # REBOOT_REMOTE_CONSOLE
},
{
  "id": 50369 # BANDWIDTH_250_GB
},
{
  "id": 35310 # NESSUS_VULNERABILITY_ASSESSMENT_REPORTING
},
{
  "id": 96833 # 1_GBPS_PUBLIC_PRIVATE_NETWORK_UPLINKS-dup
},
{
  "id": 34807 # 1_IP_ADDRESS
},
{
  "id": 33483 # UNLIMITED_SSL_VPN_USERS_1_PPTP_VPN_USER_PER_ACCOUNT
},
{
  "id": 32627 # AUTOMATED_NOTIFICATION
}
```

]

}

Answer (score 0):

To order a virtual server on a dedicated host you must to order a dedicated virtual server (private virtual server) and not a public virtual server.

Below you can see an example to order a dedicated virtual server on a dedicated host:

```
    order = 
    {
    "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest",
    "quantity": 1,
    "useHourlyPricing": true,
    "hardware": [
        {
        "hostname": "hostname0", 
        "domain": "softlayer.com"
        }
    ],
    "packageId": 46,
    "prices": [
    {"id": 200313}, // "keyName": "GUEST_CORE_4_DEDICATED", "description": "4 x 2.0 GHz or higher Cores (Dedicated Host)"
    {"id": 200353}, // "keyName": "RAM_8_UNIT_DEDICATED", "description": "8 GB (Dedicated Host)"
    {"id": 45466},  // "keyName": "OS_CENTOS_7_X_MINIMAL_64_BIT", "description": "CentOS 7.x - Minimal Install (64 bit)"
    {"id": 200397}, // "keyName": "GUEST_DISK_100_GB_LOCAL_DEDICATED_HOST", "description": "100 GB (Local - Dedicated Host)"
    {"id": 200425}, // "keyName": "GUEST_DISK_400_GB_LOCAL_DEDICATED_DISK1", "description": "400 GB (Local - Dedicated Host)"
    {"id": 1800},   // "keyName": "BANDWIDTH_0_GB_2", "description": "0 GB Bandwidth Allotment"
    {"id": 203857}, // "keyName": "100_MBPS_PUBLIC_PRIVATE_NETWORK_UPLINKS_DEDICATED", "description": "100 Mbps Public & Private Network Uplinks (Dedicated Host)"
    {"id": 55},     // "keyName": "MONITORING_HOST_PING", "description": "Host Ping"
    {"id": 58},     // "keyName": "AUTOMATED_NOTIFICATION", "description": "Automated Notification"
    {"id": 420},    // "keyName": "UNLIMITED_SSL_VPN_USERS_1_PPTP_VPN_USER_PER_ACCOUNT", "description": "Unlimited SSL VPN Users & 1 PPTP VPN User per account"
    {"id": 418},    // "keyName": "NESSUS_VULNERABILITY_ASSESSMENT_REPORTING", "description": "Nessus Vulnerability Assessment & Reporting"
    {"id": 21},     // "keyName": "1_IP_ADDRESS", "description": "1 IP Address"
    {"id": 57},     // "keyName": "NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_AND_TICKET", "description": "Email and Ticket"
    {"id": 905}     // "keyName": "REBOOT_REMOTE_CONSOLE", "description": "Reboot / Remote Console"
    ],
    "hostId": 11111
}
```

It is correct to use the packageId 46 for dedicated virtual server.

You have to provide a "hostId", where you will host your vs.

There is another option to order a dedicated virtual server using Auto Assign where you will not need a dedicated host capacity, you just have to select a location.

See the below example:

```
    order = 
    {
    "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest",
    "quantity": 1,
    "useHourlyPricing": true,
    "hardware": [
        {
        "hostname": "hostname0", 
        "domain": "softlayer.com"
        }
    ],
    "location" : 449596, // "longName": "Melbourne 1"
    "packageId": 46,
    "prices": [
    {"id": 52295}, // "keyName": "GUEST_PRIVATE_CORE_1", "description": "1 x 2.0 GHz or higher Cores (Dedicated)"        
    {"id": 51215}, // "keyName": "RAM_1_GB", "description": "1 GB"
    {"id": 45466}, // "keyName": "OS_CENTOS_7_X_MINIMAL_64_BIT"
    {"id": 2202},  // "keyName": "GUEST_DISK_25_GB_SAN", "description": "25 GB (SAN)"
    {"id": 1800},  // "keyName": "BANDWIDTH_0_GB_2", "description": "0 GB Bandwidth Allotment"
    {"id": 273},   // "keyName": "100_MBPS_PUBLIC_PRIVATE_NETWORK_UPLINKS", "description": "100 Mbps Public & Private Network Uplinks"
    {"id": 55},    // "keyName": "MONITORING_HOST_PING"
    {"id": 58},    // "keyName": "AUTOMATED_NOTIFICATION"
    {"id": 420},   // "keyName": "UNLIMITED_SSL_VPN_USERS_1_PPTP_VPN_USER_PER_ACCOUNT"
    {"id": 418},   // "keyName": "NESSUS_VULNERABILITY_ASSESSMENT_REPORTING"
    {"id": 21},    // "keyName": "1_IP_ADDRESS"
    {"id": 57},    // "keyName": "NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_AND_TICKET"
    {"id": 905}    // "keyName": "REBOOT_REMOTE_CONSOLE"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes I understand to order a dedicated virtual server I need to specify a host id but I am trying to test using the ordering system by just ordering a public cloud VSI first.  If I am querying `product_package.getItemPrices` on package ID 46 to get the price IDs why am I getting a rather vague error message when using those price IDs?  How are you getting your price IDs?

Comment: The error with your price ids is because some of them belong to the 835 package and another to the 46 package, one of them is the id: 203987, it belongs to the package 835 and you are using the package 46. To get the price ids I use the same method "getItemPrices". In the following link you can see an example in python how to order a vs: https://sldn.softlayer.com/python/order_vsi_friendly.py/

Comment: I have updated my question with the correct price IDs for package 46 but this still throws the same error for location Mel01 449596

Comment: I tried the request and it is working for me, The problem in your json data is the 'complexType' : 'Softlayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest', in the "Softlayer" data, the letter "l" must be uppercase like this "SoftLayer". Try with this 'complexType': 'SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest' and the request will work.

Comment: Ah thank you!   Good pick up I have been caught out with this before when importing the library but because the error message was referring to price ids I didn't think to check that.  Thanks again @F.Ojeda